# How to create a two level listview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Just started to work with android and I cannot find a good example for a listview with two levels. I came across the `ExpandableListView`, but this it not the list I m looking for.

Basically, I want to build a list, which shows a topic like a genre (f.e. comedy, drama..) and if you click on the genre, it should open a list, where only the movies of the specific genre are shown (f.e. click on comedy -> "new list" with only comedy-movies is shown, so the genres aren't shown anymore)

`ExpandableListView` creates something like a Node Tree, which doesn t fit my needs. Anyone any good examples or recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have one activity show the top level. When the user clicks on it, start up another activity to show the second level.

Comment: you mean, instead of one 'TwoLevelListActivity' I would have a 'TopLevelListActivity' which shows my genres and calls on click a 'SecondLevelListActivity' which simply receives the SecondLevelData?!..makes sense

Comment: @longilong: Correct. Or, use two fragments, replacing the first-level `ListFragment` with the second-level `ListFragment` via a `replace()` `FragmentTransaction`.